# Member is not a structure or union

Tags: c++, c++11

When I compile this demo code I was told I had an error where I didn't define `n`. Now I tried to define `n` as an `int` but it tells me this error. I also had the same problem with using char. Is this meant to be a string instead and if so how do I define it?

```
src/main.cpp:22:32: error: member reference base type 'char' is not a structure or union
    auto found = tagmaps.find(n.name());
                              ~^~~~~
src/main.cpp:49:24: error: member reference base type 'char' is not a structure or union
        found = tagmaps.find(n.name());
                             ~^~~~~
```

This is my full code:

```
#include "pugi/pugixml.hpp"

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>

int main()
{

    // Define mappings, default left - map on the right
    const std::map<std::string, std::string> tagmaps
    {
        {"id", "id"}
        , {"description", "content"}
    }
    int n;
    pugi::xml_document doca, docb;
    auto found = tagmaps.find(n.name());
    std::map<std::string, pugi::xml_node> mapa, mapb;

    if (!doca.load_file("a.xml") || !docb.load_file("b.xml")) { 
        std::cout << "Can't find input files";
        return 1;
    }

    for (auto& node: doca.child("data").children("entry")) {
    const char* id = node.child_value("id");
    mapa[id] = node;
    }

    for (auto& node: docb.child("data").children("entry")) {
    const char* idcs = node.child_value("id");
        if (!mapa.erase(idcs)) {
        mapb[idcs] = node;
        }
    }

    for (auto& ea: mapa) {
    std::cout << "Removed:" << std::endl;
    ea.second.print(std::cout);
    }

    for (auto& eb: mapb) {
    // change node name if mapping found
    found = tagmaps.find(n.name());
        if((found != tagmaps.end()) {
        n.set_name(found->second.c_str());
        }
    }
```

EDIT: This code is meant to check if any of the node names match what is defined in the map, i.e it would look for any nodes called `id` and `content`

Comment: What do you expect `n.name()` to do? Do you understand the syntax?

Comment: No, a string won't work because it still doesn't have a `name()` member function, same as `int` and `char`.

Comment: `name()` on `int` only works with `type_info` class `typeid(n).name();` If that is even what you want

Comment: @puelo, Something tells me `n` stands for node and that there's some node class with a `name` member.

Comment: @puelo: not really. Any class can define a `name` function... like `pugi::xml_node` does. Maybe that's the expected type of `n` but without more context it's hard to tell.

Comment: @chris Yes. Just realized. I don't believe my comment will help then. I specified a bit.

Comment: This is the third question you've asked about this piece of code. You keep getting your variable names wrong. Is there a lesson to be learnt here?

Comment: @LightningRacisinObrit I've just spent all day trying to learn C++ but it's all a bit new and I appreciate the help

Comment: @Mat Honestly, no, I don't. Its meant to see if it can find the name defined in the map as a node name

Comment: You cannot learn C++ in a _day_. Try three years! What I'm saying is that you need to take more caution and care and read your own code. Being new to C++ does not absolve you of that responsibility; it's an everyday skill in all walks of life.

Comment: What you need is `find("id")` or `find("description")` as an example.

Comment: I've put an edit on my code to try and explain what I am trying to achieve.  In my case I am trying to take the node and find if any of the sub nodes match the definition in the map (i.e "id" or "content")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your map requires an `std::string` as the key, but you use an `int` and furthermore, access that `int` as if it were some structure/class.

```
int n;
...n.name()...
```

Even if you change `n` to an `std::string` it doesn't have a method `name()`.

Comment: So it needs to be defined as a string but also I need to define a method(). I was under the impression that pugi gave me this but i need to read the docs again I guess

Comment: It is not clear from your code, what the requirement is. You need to implement a method if you want to have some function that returns the string that is to be searched. The bottom line is that you need something that gives you a string which you can search for.